# Как получить testName из аннотации @Test?

Tags: java, testng

Используя testNG, я могу передать в аннотацию теста имя теста @Test(testName = "Test name"). Как я в последствии могу получить это имя?

Comment: Для каких целей это необходимо? просто так в `TestNG` в самом тесте имя не получить.

Comment: я хочу пометить каждый свой тест идентификатором, чтобы при логировании в логе вытягивать этот ид

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример такого подхода:

```java
package click.webelement.testng;

import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestName {

    String name;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void configure(ITestResult result){
        name = result.getMethod().getDescription();
    }

    @Test(description = "This is my test")
    public void myTest(){
        System.out.println("Running: " + name);
    }

}
```

Дело в том, что `@Test(testName = "Test name")` можно использовать только на уровне всего класса, а не отдельного метода. Для методова есть параметр `description`.

Он хранится в объекте `ITestResult`, который `TestNG` не умеет инджектить напрямую в тестовый метод. Зато умеет инджектить его в `@BeforeMethod`. Там его можно сохранить в поле и использовать его в самом тесте.

Comment: Большое спасибо :)